# Sum and Group Query doesn't group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to filter records and then sum and group those records, in my controller I have done it like so:

```
  def view
     @templates = Template.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} OR user_id = 1").where("category = 5")
     @user_docs = Doc.where("user_id = #{current_user.id}")
     @transactions = Transaction.where("doc_id in (?)", @user_docs.map(&:id)).where("template_id in (?)", @templates.map(&:id))
     @month = @transactions.select("DATE_TRUNC('month', date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS total_amount_per_month").group('month')
  end
```

It gives an error with the month grouping and the amount is the total of all the months summed in my view, any idea why the above isn't working? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I got an error at the date was because the date was added later to my model with a migration and I didn't add it to attributes accessible. After that the error was fixed.